# How use JAWR 3.7 library with IntelliJ ? (in Eclipse it working but in IntelliJ shows error)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, intellij-idea, jawr

We use [JAWR](https://jawr.java.net/) 3.7 library for bundling and minification.
Our web server is Apache 8.0.26

when We run project in Eclipse 4.5 run without any problem but when
using intellij as IDE and run it

**we see this error**

**Exception Detail :**
[image]

**Code Detail :**

*jawr.properties :*

```
# Common properties

jawr.debug.on=false
jawr.gzip.on=true
jawr.gzip.ie6.on=false
jawr.charset.name=UTF-8

jawr.css.bundle.all.id=/content/css/all.css
jawr.css.bundle.all.mappings=/WEB-INF/Resources/css/bootstrap.css\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/css/alertify/alertify_core.css\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/css/alertify/alertify_bootstrap.css

jawr.css.bundle.mine.id=/content/css/myall.css
jawr.css.bundle.mine.mappings=/WEB-INF/Resources/css/all2.css

jawr.js.bundle.jquery.id=/content/js/jquery.js
jawr.js.bundle.jquery.mappings=\
  /WEB-INF/Resources/js/jquery-2.0.3.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/bootstrap.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/alertify/alertify.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/jquery.ui.widget.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/jquery.fileupload.js\

jawr.js.bundle.angular.id=/content/js/angular.js
jawr.js.bundle.angular.mappings=/WEB-INF/Resources/js/angular.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/angular-resource.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/angular-route.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/angular-animate.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/angular-touch.js


jawr.js.bundle.app.id=/content/js/app.js
jawr.js.bundle.app.mappings=/WEB-INF/Resources/js/app/app.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/app/globalController.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/app/defaultController.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/app/customerController.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/app/jewelleryController.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/app/orderController.js\
  ,/WEB-INF/Resources/js/sg/sg-all.js
```

*Startup class :*

```
public class Startup implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        WebApplicationContext context = this.getContext();

        ContextLoaderListener listener = new ContextLoaderListener(context);
        servletContext.addListener(listener);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherServlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcherServlet.addMapping("/");


        ServletRegistration.Dynamic javascriptServlet = servletContext.addServlet("javascriptServlet" , new JawrServlet());
        javascriptServlet.setInitParameter("configLocation", "org/risman/config/jawr.properties");
        javascriptServlet.setInitParameter("type", JawrConstant.JS_TYPE);
        javascriptServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        javascriptServlet.addMapping("*.js");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic styleServlet = servletContext.addServlet("styleServlet" , new JawrServlet());
        styleServlet.setInitParameter("configLocation", "org/risman/config/jawr.properties");
        styleServlet.setInitParameter("type", JawrConstant.CSS_TYPE);
        styleServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        styleServlet.addMapping("*.css");

    }


    private WebApplicationContext getContext() {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();


        context.register(WebConfig.class);

        return context;

    }

}
```

*Web.config :*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan( basePackages= {"org.risman.controller" })//, "org.risman.repository" , "org.risman.service"} )
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/Resources/")
                .resourceChain(true).addResolver(new GzipResourceResolver());

    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/Views/");

        return resolver;

    }

}
```

*index.jsp :*

```
<head>

    <%@ taglib prefix="jw" uri="http://jawr.net/tags" %>
    <%--<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>--%>


    <jw:style src="/content/css/all.css" useRandomParam="false"></jw:style>
    <jw:style src="/content/css/myall.css" useRandomParam="false"></jw:style>

    <jw:script src="/content/js/jquery.js" useRandomParam="false" async="false"></jw:script>
    <jw:script src="/content/js/angular.js" useRandomParam="false" async="false"></jw:script>
    <jw:script src="/content/js/app.js" useRandomParam="false" async="false"></jw:script>


    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

Why our codes work on ECLIPSE but error in IntelliJ ???!!!!

seems all config,codes,web server, ... in the same

Comment: It looks like jawr has not initialized at startup.  Please show your startup logs.